# rbenv installation permission denied

Tags: ruby, terminal, rbenv

Hi all I'm trying to set up a dev environment and I've been following a tutorial via;
[Link to tutorial](http://mac-dev-env.patrickbougie.com/ruby-rbenv/)

I'm not doing very well and have no real experience of terminal commands other than the most basic version control stuff. I followed the first link and when trying to run

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

I got the error; 
`mkdir: /usr/local/rbenv/shims: Permission denied
mkdir: /usr/local/rbenv/versions: Permission denied`

Now every time I load terminal the error appears.

Contents of bash_profile;

```
export PATH=/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post the contents of `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Yep, I've added it to the question.

Comment: It looks like the rbenv setup puts a line of shell scripting in your .bash_profile that attempts to create that directory. You could either give yourself permissions to create directories in /usr/local/rbenv, or `sudo mkdir /directories/that/need/to/be/created` once.

Comment: Yep that's the one Greg, thanks fella. If you go ahead and answer it I'll make sure to up vote. Cheers man.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the rbenv setup puts a line of shell scripting in your `.bash_profile` that attempts to create that directory. You could either give yourself permissions to create directories in `/usr/local/rbenv`, or `sudo mkdir /directories/that/need/to/be/created` once.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/rbenv/shims
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/rbenv/versions
```

Comment: You should not create those folder yourself, `rbenv` is capable of doing it itself if it needs to. The only thing you should do is run `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` when you launch terminal using init scripts. More info in this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65999645/512504

Answer (score 7):

I was getting a permissions error when trying to install a ruby version.

It also was complaining that it couldn't complete the mkdir

In short set LDFLAGS to a blank string.

```
export LDFLAGS=
```

Was found here:
https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/766

Comment: I had a `mkdir /usr/local/opt` error with `rbenv install` after migrating a `.bashrc` from an AMD64 Mac to an ARM64 Mac, and the install location for homebrew changed.

In my `.bashrc` I had these lines in the file originally `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/sqlite/lib"` and `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include"`. When I updated them to: `export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/lib"` and `export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/sqlite/include"` all was fixed.

Comment: `LDFLAGS="" rbenv install` worked for me, in case you don't want to always export blank LDFLAGS.

Comment: on OSX, you can do `env LDFLAGS= rbenv install`

Answer (score 4):

The *actual* solution ;-) (without the need of changing permissions or creating directories) is to change your `bash_profile` (or other like `.zshrc` as in my case) and **remove** the two exports:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/rbenv/bin:$PATH
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv
```

Start a new shell, to be sure, and execute your `rbenv install <your_version_of_choice>` and it will install without any issues.

Running `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` should be enough for your environment. See [rbenv init explained](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-rbenv-hooks-into-your-shell).
I also think this is safer as you rely on the install to do it's work properly.

Gems are installed without the need of root/sudo.

Answer (score 3):

This was pretty useful [System Wide Install With rbenv](http://blakewilliams.me/posts/system-wide-rbenv-install/)
Specifically changing the permissions of rbenv directory to a group the users are in:

chgrp -R staff /usr/local/rbenv
chmod -R g+rwxXs /usr/local/rbenv