# Problem installing bundler, Says it installs, but then doesn't actually install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv

I am setting up a new system. I'm using rbenv instead of rvm because rvm changes the definition of 'cd' and that's just evil.

I've got the required version of ruby and rails (I think) installed, but bundler is causing problems:

```
turlingdrome$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/brianp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/CHANGELOG.md

turlingdrome$ sudo gem install bundler
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/rbenv.d/exec/gem-rehash/rubygems_plugin.rb:6: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/brianp/work in PATH, mode 040777
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.1
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.1
Done installing documentation for bundler after 3 seconds
1 gem installed

turlingdrome$ sudo gem uninstall bundler
Gem 'bundler' is not installed

turlingdrome$ bundler install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from /Users/brianp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/bin/bundler:23:in `<main>'
    1: from /Users/brianp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:308:in `activate_bin_path'
/Users/brianp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:289:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundler (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

So, I tried using sudo once, and now I think that the permissions are super user... so I'm using sudo. no big deal.

Installing appears to work.

When I try to uninstall, it says it's not installed.

When I try to run it, it finds an executable, but then says it can't find an executable.

I'm using ruby 2.5.3 and rails (I think) 5.2.3.

Rails crashes with:

```
turlingdrome$ rails -v
/Users/brianp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/app_loader.rb:53: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/brianp/work in PATH, mode 040777
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    3: from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
    2: from /Users/brianp/work/online-reporting/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /Users/brianp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/brianp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
```

which I assume is the same issue.

In case this matters, I'm on a mac.

Comment: after reinstalling bundler you need to run `rbenv rehash` [and follow all this steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602806/bundler-not-working-with-rbenv-could-not-find-gem#11146496)

Comment: while the bundler error  [`find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038218/7295772) is because you upgraded to bundler 2.0. You need to use bundler 1.9.0

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [rbenv works by inserting a directory of shims at the front of your PATH](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#understanding-shims):

```
~/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

> Through a process called rehashing, rbenv maintains shims in that directory to match every Ruby command across every installed version of Ruby—irb, gem, rake, rails, ruby, and so on.
>
> Shims are lightweight executables that simply pass your command along to rbenv. So with rbenv installed, when you run, say, rake, your operating system will do the following:
>
> - Search your `PATH` for an executable file named rake
> - Find the rbenv shim named rake at the beginning of your `PATH`
> - Run the shim named `rake`, which in turn passes the command along to rbenv

You messed up your `rbenv` installation.

1) [Remove ruby installation outside rbenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753785/how-to-remove-ruby-from-ubuntu#22753859)

2) [`rvm implode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558656/how-can-i-remove-rvm-ruby-version-manager-from-my-system)

3) Clean up your `$PATH` env variable from `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`

Remove any `$PATH` reference pointing to `ruby`, `irb`, `gem` or any folder including those bin executable. Consider commenting any `$PATH` statement from your `bash_profile`

```
# export PATH="$HOME/etc/bin:$PATH"
# leave the statement below 
# export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
```

The `$PATH` variable includes a list of folders:

```
echo $PATH
home/fabrizio/.rbenv/shims:/opt/android-studio/bin:~/.scripts/bin
```

if you run `gem` in your terminal

any `.bin` executable file included in `home/fabrizio/.rbenv/shims` or `/opt/android-studio/bin` is executable from any location in the terminal. When you run `gem`, [the `ruby` gem command](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems#installation) is executed instead of being intercepted from rbenv, because you installed ruby outside of rbenv.

**UPDATE BASED ON YOUR FEEDBACK**

[You must have followed this step when installing ruby 2.5.0 without rbenv](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Ruby#Setup) so remove from your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` the following line

```
PATH="$PATH:$(ruby -e 'puts Gem.user_dir')/bin"
```

or any other line which is adding `/Users/brianp/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin` to your `$PATH`, then [uninstall ruby with apt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5977587/7295772).

[Read the following information](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installing-ruby-gems), additionally always check the location where gems are being installed with gem env:

```
$ gem env home
# => ~/.rbenv/versions/<ruby-version>/lib/ruby/gems/...
```

if the location from anywhere in the terminal is not under `~/.rbenv/` then you are installing the gems in the wrong locations.

**LAST RESORT**

**Delete the gem folder with `rm -rf ~/.gem`**, [a similar approach to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536137/7295772) if you can not remove `/Users/brianp/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin` from your `$PATH`

**SOLUTION FOR YOUR LAST ERROR**

This error is caused from installing [`bundler 2.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038218/7295772)

```
  can't find gem bundler (>= 0.a) with executable bundle (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

you need to remove `bundler 2.0` and install `1.9.0`

Comment: I agree that I shouldn't sudo. But I think I'm clean on that now. $PATH is /Users/brianp/.rbenv/shims:/Users/brianp/bin/linux:.:/Users/brianp/.rbenv/shims:/Users/brianp/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin: 

Not sure why I have two copies of shims, but that is irrelevant. 'which gem' and 'which ruby' etc all point to the correct place. even which bundle...

Comment: oh, and I don't have rvm installed at all. I learned my lessen on a previous computer...

Comment: @BrianPostow bundler is being installed under `/Users/brianp/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin` and not `~/.rbenv/...` so `rbenv` can not use the `bundler` gem. You installed ruby through some other software or repository and now you have in your `$PATH` the binaries from `/Users/brianp/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin` . This means that when you run `gem install bundler`, the `gem` executable `/Users/brianp/.gem/ruby/2.5.0/bin/gem` is being used, not the one `~/.rbenv/.../gem` and this causes your error, because `.rbenv` did not install the bundler gem under `~/.rbenv`

Comment: @BrianPostow 
**Delete the gem folder with `rm -rf ~/.gem`**, [a similar approach to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11536137/7295772).

Comment: I don't see any other ruby... I'm on a mac, so brew instead of apt, but there is a /usr/bin/ruby...

When I delete the ~/.gem folder, and install bundler, it comes back. All other gems appear to be in .rbenv, which is weird...

Comment: gem env gives:   - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/brianp/.gem/ruby/2.5.0

Comment: @BrianPostow you are right, mac comes by default installed with ruby. Stupid question, did you try `rbenv rehash` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192785/discussion-between-fabrizio-bertoglio-and-brian-postow).

Comment: @BrianPostow your last error is caused from installing `bundler 2.0` . You need to downgrade to `bundler 1.9.0`.

Comment: after reinstalling bundler you need to run `rbenv rehash` [and follow all this steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602806/bundler-not-working-with-rbenv-could-not-find-gem#11146496)

Comment: @BrianPostow Thanks a lot. Please ping me and lets talk again in chat to solve your issues until you have rbenv working.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `rbenv` is a good choice to manage `ruby` installation on Mac, but it seems that you finished up in a complete mess of broken `rbenv/gem/rails/bundler` installation and permissions. It it is not worth of fixing it, so I suggest to just get rid of `rbenv`, remove `~/.rbenv` directory and install `rbenv` with [`brew`](https://brew.sh/) again using [this guide](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos).

Other ways to check:

1. Run `rbenv-doctor`

   `curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash`
2. Remove `~/.rbenv` directory, run `rbenv init` again and install required version of Ruby
3. Check that `which ruby` and `which gem` points to appropriate location inside `~/.rbenv` directory

Things to note:

1. `rbenv` and `brew`, as well as `gem` do not require `sudo`, so you should never use it with them
2. Do not forget to add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in your shell init script, e.g. `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: hmm, that doesn't seem to have helped. I'll add more in OP.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a permission issue on a folder.

> permission denied @ rb_sysopen -
>    /Users/brianp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-2.0.1/CHANGELOG.md

I'd try to change permissions on the mentioned file / folder using `chmod 755 /Users/brianp/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/`

There are several posts which handle a similar topic, e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588604/rbenv-installation-permission-denied).

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

> warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/brianp/work in PATH, mode 040777

Looks like problem with access rights. Try this:

```
sudo chmod 755 /Users/brianp/work
```

Comment: That's just a security warning. I'm the only person on my machine, so it's not relevant... But I did it anyway, and it didn]'t help

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete `Gemfile.lock`and try to install and use bundler again - I have just found [that](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/6882) on Github:

> Bundler 2 introduced a new feature that will automatically switch between Bundler v1 and v2 based on the lockfile [...] If you do, it can be fixed by installing the version of Bundler that is declared in the lockfile. This bug was fixed in RubyGems 3.0.0 but backports are now being prepared for previous major versions of RubyGems. We’ll let you know when they become available.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try that?

```
gem install bundler --user-install
```